# Is there a way I can create a hash of the contents of a NVARCHAR column with chinese characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with thousands of rows. I would like to make it so that the user can select a group of these at at time.

Is it possible to create a hash function value of a `NVARCHAR` column of Chinese characters (similar to the way I do with the ascii function) and put this into another column.

If this was possible I would hope to be able to select say from the trailing last digit of the hash value a 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0  That way I could easily select a group of 10% of the columns.

Here is the DDL that I have for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] 
(
    [PhraseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    [EnglishAscii] AS (ASCII(UPPER([English]))) PERSISTED,
    [Kanji] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseChapter] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ChapterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseChapter] ([PhraseChapterShortId])
);
```

Note that I tried using `ASCII` function for the Kanji column and it just returns 63 for every row.

Comment: Wait, **Why** do you want to hash the data? Are you trying to select random rows?

Comment: `ASCII()` doesn't hash anything. It returns the ASCII value of a *single* character. When applied to a string, it returns the ASCII value of the *first* character. For Unicode data, the equivalent function is called [UNICODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ASCII](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) doesn't hash anything. It returns the ASCII value of a single **ASCII** character. When applied to a string, it returns the ASCII value of the first character.

Applying `ASCII()` it to an NVARCHAR column is a *bug*, as any non-English characters will be treated as if they were encoded with a codepage that matches the server's collation. The same query run on different servers, will return a different value.

Even worse, if the first character can't be represented in the server's collation, you'll get the equivalent of `?` - ASCII 63. This is the replacement character when a character in one codepage can't be mapped to another codepage.

For Unicode data, the equivalent function is called [UNICODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx).

If you wanted to return rows based on group of characters, a *far* faster option would be to use the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator, eg:

```
select * from Phrase
where 
    English like N'[A表]%' OR 
    Kanji like N'[A表]%'
```

`LIKE` can take advantage of any indexes that cover the fields and perform a range search instead of scanning the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the only hashing algorithms offered by sql server. Given that I dont think it is possible to create hash with chinese characters.

**sql server 2005 and above**

```
MD 2 (MD2)
MD 4 (MD4)
MD 5 (MD5)
SHA-0 (SHA)
SHA-1 (SHA1)
```

**newly introduced in sql server 2012**

```
SHA-2 256 bits AKA SHA-256 (SHA2_256)
SHA-2 512 bits AKA SHA-512 (SHA2_512)
```

**Note:** Hashing is usually achieved in sql server using **HASHBYTES** function. MD5 and SHA1 are most commonly used to avoid duplicates/collisions in hash values

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a `CHECKSUM` caclulated column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]      NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [EnglishAscii] AS               (ascii(upper([English]))) PERSISTED,
    [Kanji]        NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [KanjiCS]      CHECKSUM([Kanjii],
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PhrasePhraseChapter] FOREIGN KEY ([ChapterId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PhraseChapter] ([PhraseChapterShortId])
);
```

According to this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) `CHECKSUM` 'Returns the checksum value computed over a row of a table, or over a list of expressions. CHECKSUM is intended for use in building hash indexes.'

Comment: That's a *checksum*, not a hash. It's far too easy to get collisions